# Paying a Cost and Communicating

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have four [Burning-Tree Emissary](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Burning-Tree%20Emissary) and one [Firefist Striker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Firefist%20Striker) on the field. My opponent is in his Precombat Main Phase. We are under Competitive Rules Enforcement Level (REL). The following actions occur in order.

1. My opponent taps three [Swamp](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Swamp).
2. My opponent announces that he is casting [Bile Blight](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bile%20Blight) targeting a Burning-Tree Emissary, which he points at.
3. Silence for three seconds.
4. My opponent taps two Swamp.
5. My opponents announces that he is casting [Devour Flesh](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Devour%20Flesh) targeting me.
6. I immediately offer to let Devour Flesh resolve (because I am super excited that I now get the opportunity to sacrifice the target of Bile Blight).

Here is where the problem begins. My opponent tried to back out of his play by declaring that he had not yet paid the costs for Devour Flesh. I had assumed that the mana he produced from his swamps was going to pay for his spell, but he didn't explicitly *say* that.

What verbal and nonverbal actions must one take to pay the costs for a spell? Are there any weird exceptions like "I didn't take my hand off the card" or other? How can I confirm that a cost has been paid without being ridiculously annoying and tedious?

Comment: Note that he didn't have priority to cast a second spell. From my answer to your previous question, "Whenever a player adds an object to the stack, he or she is assumed to be passing priority unless he or she explicitly announces that he or she intends to retain it. [...]"

Comment: Was Bile Blight already in his graveyard when playing Devour Flesh? if so I can imagine that he thought you let him resolve Bile Blight before playing Devour Flesh

Comment: @IvoBeckers: surely he would have waited with playing Devour Flesh until everything was resolved then? (e.g., the emissaries would have been in the graveyard)

Comment: I think Ikegami has the right of things here. Point 3 implies implicit priority passing from both parties. If the asker allows his opponents second spell to be put onto the stack, surely he has implicitly passed priority on the first spell, allowing it to resolve? That makes the rest just out of order sequencing.

Comment: @Patters It looks like you are right and that paying the cost was only a secondary issue. Just to restate what you said in a words that I can better understand, *"If a player would add multiple objects onto the stack with explicitly retaining priority, they are choosing to apply the standard tournament shortcut that each one would resolve before the next one is added."* This was one of the harder concepts for me to comprehend, because it makes the Stack behave like a Queue, which is a completely different structure.

Comment: You rarely want to respond to your own spells, so it's simpler.

Comment: I think your confusion stemmed from the issue of shortcuts. The stack always behaves like a stack. But you are right in this case the stack looks like its being a queue. It's the lack of communication that's to blame, and that's on both your heads. Strictly speaking your opponent should check his spell resolves before casting another one. If you want his other spell to still be on the stack, you should get agreement it is still there before you let his new spell on the stack. In the absence of both of these, the silence has to be taken as tacit priority passes. in essence: More words = good

Comment: @Patters I decided this was a little too nitpicky to be useful as a new question, so I will ask here. Exactly how and when do you communicate intent to hold priority? Is there a timer? Must it be one contiguous motion of "I'll cast this, target that, use this mana, and retain priority"? If I announce a spell and then pause to consider what land I want to tap to pay for the spell, have I already lost priority?

Comment: Decide first. "I cast this, and in response I do Y" would normally work. Then, you can worry about moving cards and tapping others. (Note: I have no actual experience in tournaments.)

Comment: I said "decide first", but there's really nothing to decide. I imagine it's quite rare to you would have cast the first spell at all if you weren't already planning on responding.

Comment: I think it's worth emphasizing that there really are two distinct questions here: can your opponent back out of casting Devour Flesh, and has their Bile Blight resolved (i.e., will you have to sacrifice your Firefist Striker).  I agree that ikegami's answer makes the former clear, but these comments should emphasize that even at Competitive REL the latter is _also_ true; your opponent gave you time to respond, you didn't explicitly do so, and while he should have asked 'resolves?' for explicit confirmation, the shortcut rules mean that the spell _will_ have resolved...

Comment: ...and if not (that is, if you had something that _you_ wanted to add to the stack), the game state should be *rewound* to before Devour Flesh was cast, and your opponent _will_ be able to 'back out'.

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki Re: "the shortcut rules mean that the spell will have resolved", What shortcut? The one I mentioned? That's not true. The OP would have had to say "pass" or some such for it to resolve. His opponent is playing out of turn; no spell has resolved. Remember, only the active player can propose a shortcut, so his opponent can't do anything at all at this point according to the rules. Now, if you have tournament experience and you're saying it's different, let me know.

Comment: @ikegami Non-active players *can* propose shortcuts. There are no real rules surrounding shortcuts except that 1) there is a list of formal shortcuts that are understood by all judges, (e.g., "Pass turn", "Go", "Combat?", etc.) and 2) any shortcut not on that list is ok to use only if both players understand what is happening. Point number two is actually relevant to our discussion. The shortcut my opponent used was not one that we both understood, so it really shouldn't have happened at all.

Comment: I regularly play one of the few decks where retaining priority after casting a spell matters - Legacy Tendrils Storm. It includes the "combo" of Lion's Eye Diamond and Infernal Tutor. I have to retain priority after casting infernal tutor so that I can activate LED (despite being a mana ability, I can only activate LED when I can cast an instant). Most of the time, it's fine if you dont explicitly say, providing you do the next action with no pause. Saying that, strictly speaking, if people want to be really rigid on the rules, you HAVE to say "retaining priority", so its best to do so

Comment: @Rusher, 1) What are you talking about? There's a whole section in the rules about shortcuts (716). 2) I meant the player with priority, not the active player. "716.2. Taking a shortcut follows the following procedure. 716.2a At any point in the game, the player with priority may suggest a shortcut [...]" Considering that most shortcuts are proposed by doing something that advances the game (e.g. attacking), proposing a shortcut when you don't have priority is playing out of turn, an error.

Comment: @ikegami That section of the "rules" starts off with "the rules surrounding shortcuts are largely unformalized". The rest of that section is just an over-articulated mess of words that says "You should communicate well." The real rules regarding shortcuts exist in the tournament rules, where there is a list of understood shortcuts. Players without priority *can* propose shortcuts. A common example is when a defending player without priority offers to move to the declare blockers step.

Comment: @ikegami Another common example is when a player in a multiplayer game counters a spell, which is short for "Can I have priority and then counter your spell?"

Comment: @Rusher, The TR don't define shortcuts at all; they define specific shortcuts. By the rules, "Can I have priority and then counter your spell?" isn't proposing a shortcut because you don't have priority. That's just talking. You're basically asking your opponent to propose a shortcut. Since you didn't propose a shortcut, you are not bound to counter the spell even if your opponent says yes.

Comment: @Rusher, According to the rules, neither of those are allowed. // By the rules, "Can I have priority and then counter your spell?" isn't proposing a shortcut because you don't have priority. That's just talking. You're basically asking your opponent to propose a shortcut. Since you didn't propose a shortcut, you are not bound to counter the spell even if your opponent says yes.

Comment: @ikegami "I'll cast Counterspell." *is* a shortcut for "I want to gain priority and cast Counterspell." If you propose a shortcut, but you have no intent of actually following through, you can actually receive warnings from judges for intentionally creating ambiguity. Repeatedly proposing shortcuts and then backing out of them *will* eventually earn you unsporting conduct. Read this article for a better understanding. You'll notice that throughout the article, players *without* priority are proposing shortcuts. https://www.wizards.com/Magic/Magazine/Article.aspx?x=judge/article/20071109a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My opponent tried to back out of his play by declaring that he had not yet paid the costs for Devour Flesh.

The rules don't allow him to back out in the scenario you described.

---

The following are the steps to casting a spell:

1. (601.2a) Place the card on the stack.
2. (601.2b-d) Make some choices including targets.
3. (601.2e) Determine the total cost to cast the spell.
4. (601.2f) Activate mana abilities if desired if the cost has a mana component.
5. (601.2g) Pay the total cost to cast the spell.

Not only did he announce what he is casting (part of step 601.2a), he announced targets (part of 601.2c). There's no question that he started casting the spell. There's is only one condition under which the casting of the spell can be undone: The player becomes unable to comply with the instructions<sup>[CR 601.2]</sup>. For example, the casting of the spell can be undone if the caster becomes unable to pay the spell's costs.

Let's pretend for a moment that his mana pool was empty. He cannot be forced to tap lands to produce the mana required to pay the spell<sup>[CR 117.3c]</sup>. If he chose not to tap any lands in step 601.2f, he won't be able to pay the cost when it comes time to do so in step 601.2g, which undoes the casting of the spell<sup>[CR 601.2][1]</sup>.

However, his mana pool isn't empty. He *can* comply with the instruction to pay the cost, so he must<sup>[2]</sup>. At no point is he unable to comply with any of the steps required to cast a spell, so nothing allows him to undo the casting of the spell.

---

> 601.2. [...] If, at any point during the casting of a spell, a player is unable to comply with any of the steps listed below, the casting of the spell is illegal; the game returns to the moment before that spell started to be cast [...]

> 117.3c Activating mana abilities is not mandatory, even if paying a cost is<sup>[3]</sup>.

> 601.2f If the total cost includes a mana payment, the player then has a chance to activate mana abilities (see rule 605, “Mana Abilities”). Mana abilities must be activated before costs are paid.

> 601.2g The player pays the total cost in any order. Partial payments are not allowed. Unpayable costs can’t be paid.

---

1. I don't know how tolerant judges are of this practice, but that's a separate issue.
2. If the game instructs you to do something, you must do it if you can.
3. In fact, you are never compelled to create a situation where you could pay a cost. 117.3c is just a specific case of a general rule, though the general rule appears to be unwritten. For example, see the last sentence of the first ruling on [Avatar of Slaughter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Avatar%20of%20Slaughter).

Comment: Thank you for addressing the topic of the question and not stopping at the pass of priority. I got to learn two things today.

Comment: np. The priority issue was obviously not the question.

Comment: To be fair, I think the priority issue is _part_ of the question; while the opponent can't back out of the casting of Devour Flesh, the question contains the implicit and false assumption that there's any reason for them to do so.